# Nodejs+express. Is there any way to save the sessions to REST API?

Tags: node.js, rest, session, express

All the data control is through the REST API for my web.I see session can be stored on mongo,redis, or in memory. 
this is how mongo does:

```
app.use(express.session({
    secret  : "Stays my secret",
    maxAge  : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store   : new MongoStore({ db: 'myDB' })
}));
```

But what I what is to save sessions to other REST API, any advice?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Provides cookie-based sessions, and populates req.session. This middleware takes the following options:

- key cookie name defaulting to connect.sess
- secret prevents cookie tampering
- cookie session cookie settings, defaulting to { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null }
- proxy trust the reverse proxy when setting secure cookies (via "x-forwarded-proto")

  app.use(express.cookieSession());

Comment: So you want to create a session, but store it not in memory (express.session), or in the browser (which is far and away the most scalable method, but requires limited amount of information), or in a database, but in some other REST service?